# not able to fire image click event

Tags: jquery, html

i have code like this :

i want to fire click event for 2 image inside DIV element, but 2nd image click event is not work

```
<ul style="float: left; width: 898px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px;" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" id="mycarousel">
            <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 52px;" jcarouselindex="1">
                <div style="position: relative">
                    <img width="40" height="40" style="cursor: pointer" title="Project 010" alt="image" class="5137aa052acf96352027d9a0|Project 010|Employee|5/1/2004|6/1/2011||||Descriptions**True|Skills**True|Client**true|Achievements**True|Memberships**False|Org Chart**False|Specialization**False|Get Ratings**False|" src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" id="img5137aa052acf96352027d9a0">
                    <img class="imgProjectDelete" style="position: absolute; display: none; top: 4px; right: 5px" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-2 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 52px;" jcarouselindex="2">
                <div style="position: relative">
                    <img width="40" height="40" style="cursor: pointer" title="Project 009" alt="image" class="5137aa052acf96352027d995|Project 009|Employee|5/1/2002|5/1/2004||||Descriptions**True|Skills**True|Client**true|Achievements**True|Memberships**False|Org Chart**False|Specialization**False|Get Ratings**False|" src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" id="img5137aa052acf96352027d995">
                    <img class="imgProjectDelete" style="position: absolute; top: 4px; right: 5px; display: none;" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 52px;" jcarouselindex="3">
                <div style="position: relative">
                    <img width="40" height="40" style="cursor: pointer" title="Project 008" alt="image" class="5137aa052acf96352027d987|Project 008|Employee|6/1/1994|5/1/2002||||Descriptions**True|Skills**True|Client**true|Achievements**False|Memberships**False|Org Chart**False|Specialization**False|Get Ratings**False|" src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" id="img5137aa052acf96352027d987">
                    <img class="imgProjectDelete" style="position: absolute; display: none; top: 4px; right: 5px" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

What i tired is :-

1st image click event is like this , and working fine

```
 $("#mycarousel").find("img").live("click", function () {

    });
```

2nd Image click event is like this, and not working

```
 $("#mycarousel").find(".imgProjectDelete").live("click", function () {
        alert("You CLick on Delete");
    });
```

i want to delete click event anyway !, no matter we use other element as second image

Comment: `.live ()` is depreciated. Use `.on ()`.

Comment: You may also want to consider moving all of the data currently stored in `class`, into `data()`.

Answer (score 1):

OK , i changed the Second image to

and write following things and it's working

```
$("#mycarousel").find("a").live("click", function () {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).on("click","#mycarousel .imgProjectDelete",function(e){
//your code
});
```

or if you are using older version of jquery use `.delegate`

```
$(document).delegate("#mycarousel .imgProjectDelete","click",function(e){
//your code
});
```

Comment: can you please define which image click event you are talking about in div?

Comment: BTW can you point out where is the element with id `mycarousel` in your markup

Comment: older version of jquery use .delegate ? where i need to put code, in document ready?

Comment: yes, `.on` was introduced in version  > 1.5 i think before that `.delegate` was used and now in the latest version of jquery `.delegate` is also deprecated